# My 1-year-old cries several times a night. Could it be pain and what to do about it?

Tags: infant, sleep, teeth, pain

I've got a 1-year-old chold. He's got almost 12 teeth (4 molars), he's been pretty constipated from Nurofen.

I've stopped giving Nurofen and am giving Movicol and Coloxyl as well. Seems to be working. He also has yoghurt so I'll be cutting that out starting today too.

He is fully breastfed, has solids quite well. Mostly lunch and dinner and also has those packet purees. Rafferty's Garden.

He sleeps a solid block from 7:30 - 11:30ish, **then** after that time, while I don't time it, or count how many (usually I'm out of it), he screams out in pain about every half hour. Well, it seems like pain. I've usually brought him back into bed by this point and he cries out and flings himself around. It doesn't seem like night terrors as it seems like pain to me. He sometimes wakes up and sometimes not. I'm exhausted.

Anyone experiencing this?

I'm wondering if it could be a dairy intolerance, I'm wondering should I keep him in his room despite the fact it's more exhausting to get up 10 times a night?

Any assistance or suggestions would be so helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Keep a food diary for a while. I know [**this**](http://www.healthline.com/health/pinworms?m=2#symptoms4) is gross, but it is an often overlooked cause of poor sleeping. Easy to test for, too. Always, though, when in doubt, see your doctor.

Comment: Thanks!  We actually took him to the doctor and apparently he's fine ☺

Comment: How many days/weeks has this pattern been lasting and how many minutes do you wait before getting him?

Comment: Hi Steve, Sadly he's been in out bed for a couple of weeks because I wasn't getting enough sleep. He's throwing himself around a bit too. He's crying on and off every so often, acactually it's about every half hour tonight. Not enough to fully wake though. He always sleeps soundly from 7 :30 - 12 (with a feed in the middle). I just don't get it!

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken your son to see a dentist for his teeth? I had the good fortune of having a brother-in-law dentist who looked after my son's teeth almost from birth. A neighbor's child experienced something similar to what you are going through with your child. They had a situation where the teeth were further down in the jaw (neighbor's recount) so it took longer an was more painful when his teeth came in. Their dentist taught her ways to ease the pain without medication. My brother-in-law also taught people how to treat pain of the gum and jaw with out pain medications.

I hope you find something that works for your son.

Comment: Thanks for the message. Come to think of it, he's got 12 teeth already and hes 1 year and 2 weeks old! Two molars did take flippin forever to come through! Maybe I'll take him. I actually thoughy he swollowed a AAA battery last week and raced him for an xray. He didn't but they saw he showed severe consitpation. I've since cut out Nurophen and yoghurt and seems to have helped but he's still crying out. Arrggg. I dunno. Thank you! 

Answer (score 0):

We went through a very similar issue with one of our children.  I tried all sorts of things, but we kept him in our bed with us.  Something that seemed to help was having our baby sit up a little bit.  We used what I believe is called a baby reflux board.  It basically just elevates their head a bit.  I thought that maybe because his head was so low while he slept, his mouth was possibly throbbing at night.

A few things to keep in mind with this advice.  I'm not a doctor, and if he/she is in a crib, I don't know that I would put anything in the crib with them.  Also, we alternated between two different baby pain medicines, but not for very long.  I THINK the reflux board helped the most, but it could just be that he grew out of it at the same time we used the board.

I hope that helps, and that you both get more sleep.

Comment: Thanks for that. He has alwayd hated the bassinet and cot. When he's not sleeping with me (brought him in a couple of weeks ago, or whenever it started), he sleeps on his single bed mattress in his room He's a bit old for reflux I think but it might help, willing to try!

Comment: Well, I didn't actually use it for reflux.  Just to raise their head while they slept so there wasn't as much throbbing during teething.